# Is it possible to build this function dynamically?

Tags: javascript, typescript

**Background:** In [React](https://reactjs.org/) we can map partitions of a key-value store called [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) onto the properties of a component class. This is done by a function, which we pass to a so called [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) function, which then magically wires both together. The problem is that this causes too much unnecessary boilerplate for my taste, so I would like to have an abstraction which does it automatically.

**Question:** I would like to use the following class to create the `mapStateToProps` function dynamically:

```
class Props {
    counterModel:CounterModel = null;
}
function mapStateToProps({counterModel}:Props) {
    return {
        counterModel
    };
}
```

In Vanilla JS the `mapStateToProps` function looks like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(_a) {
    var counterModel = _a.counterModel;
    return {
        counterModel: counterModel
    };
}
```

It looks like that it would be possible to use the `Function` constructor (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)) in combination with `Object.keys` to solve this. But the docs say that this "suffers from security and performance issues similar to eval". This is an acceptable trade-off to me, but maybe there is a better solution?

My JS Kung Fu is not strong enough to come up with a better solution. Is there even one?

Comment: To whom it may concern: My solution with the `Function` constructor works. The caveat is that you need to allow `'unsafe-eval'` in your Content Security Policy header. More info [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/). So technically it's a bad solution if you develop a publicly accessible app which allows user input.

Answer (score 2):

In case your state's properties always have the same name as your component's props, you can get less code by using `arrow function`, `destructing` and `shorthand object literal`:

```
var mapStateToProps = ({counterModel, anotherProp}:Props) => ({counterModel, anotherProp}));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely better than writing the complete declaration, but I would to point out that this suffers from the same problem, i.e. boilerplate and problematic refactoring.